# How to use do while loop in exception handling's try block

Tags: c++, exception

```
#include<iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class marks
{
    private:
    string name;
    int p,c,m;
    
    public:
    class Marks_Error
    {   
    };
    
    void input_name()
    {
        cout << "Enter Name : ";
        cin >> name;    
    }
    void input_Physics_Marks()
    {
        
        cout << "Enter Physics Marks : ";
        cin >> p;
        if(!(p>=0 && p<=100)) //checking that marks entered is valid or not;
            {
                throw Marks_Error(); //using throw block to transfer error to catch block;
            }
    }
    
    void input_Chemistry_Marks()
    {
        cout << "Enter Chemistry Marks : ";
        cin >> c;
        if(!(c>=0 && c<=100)) //checking that marks entered is valid or not;
            {
                throw Marks_Error(); //using throw block to transfer error to catch block;
            }
    }
    
    void input_Maths_Marks()
    {
        cout << "Enter Maths Marks : ";
        cin >> m;
        if(!(m>=0 && m<=100)) //checking that marks entered is valid or not;
            {
                throw Marks_Error(); //using throw block to transfer error to catch block;
            }
    }
    
    void display()
    {
        cout << "\nName = " << name << endl;
        cout << "Physics Marks = " << p << endl;
        cout << "Chemistry Marks = " << c << endl;
        cout << "Math Marks = " << m << endl;
    }
        
};

int main()
{

        try //using try block to check error;
        {
            marks m;
            m.input_name();
*//I want to add do while here, so it keep getting marks until I enter correct marks*
            m.input_Physics_Marks();
            m.input_Chemistry_Marks();
            m.input_Maths_Marks();
            m.display();
        }
        catch(marks::Marks_Error)
        {
            cout << "Invalid Marks";
        }

}
```

This is a simple full working code to enter marks and if the marks exceed their validation it'll display error
But the program ends when I enter >100 or <0, I want it to keep getting input of marks until I Write correct marks.
Should I add do while in try block or in the input functions
I can't do it.
Any lead would be appreciated.

Comment: I would do the validation in the individual marks inputs IE Input_Physics_Marks() otherwise you could get a correct physics mark then break validation on chemistry marks and go right to your catch not receiving chemistry or math but receiving physics

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but `input_Physics_Marks()`, `input_Chemistry_Marks()`, and `input_Maths_Marks()` are **exactly the same** except that the use a different prompt and assign their result internally to a different variable. You can implement all three of them with one function that takes a `std::string` as its argument, providing the prompt, and returns an `int`. So `void input_Physics_() { p = get_marks("Physics"); }`, `void input_Chemistry_Marks() { c = get_marks("Chemistry"); }` and `void input_Maths_Marks() { m = get_marks("Maths"); }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read my comment but I think this will fix your code to do what you wish(not compiled):

```
int main()
{

        
       marks m;
       m.input_name();
       bool moreInput = true;
       do{
       try //using try block to check error;
        {
      //I want to add do while here, so it keep getting marks until I enter correct marks
            m.input_Physics_Marks();
            m.input_Chemistry_Marks();
            m.input_Maths_Marks();
            m.display();
            moreInput = false;
        }
        catch(marks::Marks_Error)
        {
            cout << "Invalid Marks";
        }
        while(moreInput);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function that will do what you want:

```
void do_stuff()
{
    while (1) // Forever
    {
        try //using try block to check error;
        {
            marks m;
            m.input_name();
            m.input_Physics_Marks();
            m.input_Chemistry_Marks();
            m.input_Maths_Marks();
            m.display();
            return; // ending if everything weent well
        }
        catch (marks::Marks_Error)
        {
            cout << "Invalid Marks";
        }
    }
}
```

The `return` will end the function, but will only execute if everything above went right(since the `try` will jump to the `catch` Block if it didn't).

Comment: You must hate your users. <g> If the user correctly enters the physics marks and the chemistry makes, but makes a mistake in the maths marks, they'll have to enter the physics marks and the chemistry marks again, even through they were correct the first time around.

Comment: @PeteBecker xD I tried to provide the basic concept needed to solve to problem. I trust the asker to understand how to do it so that everything only has to be entered one time(using the `break` keyword). Btw: This would also be pretty inefficient since `m` is created multiple times and some code is in the try-catch block could be placed outside of it.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a situation where exceptions are appropriate. Just loop until the input is valid:

```
int result = -1;
while (result < 0 || result > 100) {
    std::cout << "Enter Physics Marks: ";
    if (!std::cin >> result) {
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(std::numeric_limts<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        result = -1;
    }
}
```